# D3 same ticks being showed twice on y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, bar-chart, axis

Same ticks value being displayed multiple times (1M in this case) on y axis. I don't think the problem is in how I'm formatting the ticks with `yAxisTickFormat`. What am I doing wrong?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-yalow-zqx1z?file=/src/GroupedBarChart.js)

```
export const yAxisTickFormat = (d) => {
  //Logic to reduce big numbers
  const limits = [1000000, 10000, 1000];
  const shorteners = ['M', 'K', 'K'];
  for (let i in limits) {
    if (d > limits[i]) {
      return (d / limits[i]).toFixed() + shorteners[i];
    }
  }
  return d;
};

const maxValue = storeData.dataset.reduce((maxAll, item) => {
  return item.values.reduce((maxItem, val) => 
    Math.max(maxItem, val.value), maxAll);
}, 0);
    
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([-120, height - 200]);

yScale.domain([maxValue, 0]);

 const yAxis = d3
  .axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .tickFormat((d) => (d === 0 ? null : '£') + yAxisTickFormat(d))
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, barMargin, 0)
  .tickPadding(10);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, problem is in number formating. You are passing `1400000` and `1200000` which are converts to 1M. Try to add several digits after comma by passing argument to `.toFixed` method

```js
export const yAxisTickFormat = (d) => {
  //Logic to reduce big numbers
  const limits = [1000000, 10000, 1000];
  const shorteners = ['M', 'K', 'K'];
  for (let i in limits) {
    if (d > limits[i]) {
      return (d / limits[i]).toFixed(1) + shorteners[i];
    }
  }
  return d;
};
```

Which will convert your numbers to 1.4m and 1.2m accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more correct `yAxisTickFormat` (tested with a snippet):

```js
const yAxisTickFormat = (d) => {
  let limit = Math.pow(10, 12);
  const shorteners = ["T", "B", "M", "K"];
  for (let i = 0; i < shorteners.length; i++) {
    if (d >= limit) {
      const zeroPad = Math.floor(d / limit) === d / limit;
      return '£ ' + (d / limit).toFixed(zeroPad ? 0 : 1) + ' ' + shorteners[i];
    }
    limit /= 1000;
  }
  return d;
};

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const ranges = [5000, 2000000, 4000000000, 3500000000000];

ranges.forEach((range, index) => {
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([range, 0]).range([0,300]);

const yAxis = d3
      .axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale)
      .tickFormat((d) => yAxisTickFormat(d))
      .ticks(10);
      
 svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${50 + index * 100},50)`).call(yAxis);     
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="400"/>
```

Comment: in this case low numbers don't have a prepend £ symbol https://imgur.com/a/RyKBNWt